# Help with the Inductive step in mathematical Induction?

Tags: induction

I just started working on Induction, and I have one particular problem that I don't understand:

Prove that $1+3+5+...+(2n−1)=n^2$ for any integer $n≥1.$

- $n = 1$  :

  $1 = 1^2$
- $n = k$  :

  $1+3+5+...+(2k−1)=k^2$
- $n = k+1$  : (this is where I have a problem)

  I thought that you simply substitute k+1 for n, yielding
  $1+3+5+...+(2k+1)$, but the correct equation is actually $1+3+5+...+(2k−1)+(2k+1)$. Where did that extra term $2k-1$ come from?

My apologies if this is a simple answer, but this is all new to me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get confused. For example, if I write the expression $2+4+6+\cdots +10$, isn't it the same as $2+4+6+\cdots 8+10$? (the sum of even integers from $2$ to $10$, inclusive). They're just including the second last term, that's all. This will be needed in order to apply the induction hypothesis (from the case $n=k$, you need the sum $1+3+5+\cdots +(2k-1)$ to appear somewhere).

This is a very common idea when trying to prove identities involving sums (or products) of $n$ terms by induction on $n$: Isolate the $n+1$ term and notice that the remaining part will be the induction hypothesis.

Comment: wow i feel silly. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @user3170251 Don't worry, it takes some time.